# Dynamically field selection for Solr Suggestion (Spellcheck) multiple term query

Tags: solr, lucene, solr-schema

I am using the solr suggestion component with the following configuration:

schema.xml

```xml
<fieldType name="textSpell" class="solr.TextField">
 <analyzer>
   <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
   <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
 </analyzer>
</fieldType>
<field name="image_memo" type="text_general"/>
<field name="username" type="text_general"/>
<field name="image_memo" type="text_general"/>
<field name="image_text" type="text_general"/>
<!-- More fields included here -->
<field name="spell" type="textSpell" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<copyField source="*" dest="spell"/>
```

solrconfig.xml

```xml
<searchComponent class="solr.SpellCheckComponent" name="suggest">
    <lst name="spellchecker">
        <str name="name">suggest</str>
        <str name="classname">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.Suggester</str>
        <str name="lookupImpl">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.tst.TSTLookup</str>
        <str name="field">spell</str>
        <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
    </lst>
</searchComponent>

<requestHandler class="org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler"
    name="/suggest">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="spellcheck">true</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">suggest</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">true</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.count">6</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.collateExtendedResults">true</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.maxCollations">6</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.maxCollationTries">1000</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">true</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.collateParam.mm">100%</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="components">
        <str>suggest</str>
        <str>query</str>
    </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

As you can see there is a field `spell` wich i am using for a suggestion queries. 
This works great even for multiple term queries.

But what I need is to search on selected fields only.
So for example I want valid suggestions only for the fields `image_memo` and `username`
The user can dynamicly add and remove fields to search.

I know that I could do something like this:

> q=(image_memo:*search* OR image_username:*search*)

But this is is slowing down dramtically if you got a lot of fields and a multiple term query.

Example: Searching in Field `memo, username, field, field1 and field2` for `term, term1 and term2.`

> ((memo:*term* OR username:*term* OR field:*term* OR field1:*term* OR
>   field2:*term*) AND (memo:*term1* OR username:*term1* OR field:*term1*
>   OR field1:*term1* OR field2:*term1*) AND (memo:*term2* OR
>   username:*term2* OR field:*term2* OR field1:*term2* OR
>   field2:*term2*))

Is there any way to dynamically select the `spell` fields. Or is there a way that I can search for specific fields only in a multivalued field

I am using Apach Solr 4 Alpha.

Comment: Could you post which solution worked for you, I see that you have not accepted the given answer. In that case, could you post the answer. I'm facing a similar challenge. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is use [Dismax](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin) or [eDismax](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax). SpellcheckComponent automatically runs every suggestion using your query params.

So, you have to query like this:

```
/suggest?q={!dismax}term1 term2 term3&qf=memo username field field1 field2
```

or

```
/suggest?q=term1 term2 term3&defType=dismax&qf=memo username field field1 field2
```

You can implement your custom queryparser if you don't want to use (e)dismax.